# How to calculate the gas fees used for deploying a smart contract using hardhat?

Tags: transactions, etherscan, goerli

I have created the following script for calculating the transaction fee for deploying smart contract using Hardhat:

```
const contractFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('Lock');
const deployTx = contractFactory.getDeployTransaction(unlockTime, { value: lockedAmount });
const contract = await contractFactory.deploy(unlockTime, { value: lockedAmount });

const receipt = await contract.deployTransaction.wait();
const transactionHash = await ethers.provider.getTransactionReceipt(receipt.transactionHash);


const gasUsed = transactionHash.gasUsed;
const gasPricePaid = await ethers.provider.getGasPrice();
const transactionFee = gasUsed.mul(gasPricePaid);
console.log(`Transaction fee paid for contract deployment: ${ethers.utils.formatEther(transactionFee)} wei`);

  console.log(
`Smart contract address: ${contract.address}}`
);
  
console.log(`Transaction fee estimated for contract deployment: ${deploymentPriceRBTC} wei`);
```

It works fine and I get results like:

```
Transaction fee paid for contract deployment: 0.000838054876525056 wei
```

However when I open the transaction on Etherscan I see that the transaction fee is different 0.00118697 for the same transaction.

Can someone explain me what is exactly happening how can I get the real value which is stored on etherscan

Comment: This - and most of the things related to testing and debugging - are easier to do with [Foundry](https://book.getfoundry.sh/), since you are testing and deploying using Solidity itself. Consider making the switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`effectiveGasPrice`** value directly from the receipt, instead of *`ethers.provider.getGasPrice`*

```csharp
const transactionReceipt = await ethers.provider.getTransactionReceipt(receipt.transactionHash);
const gasUsed = transactionReceipt.gasUsed;
const gasPricePaid = transactionReceipt.effectiveGasPrice;
const transactionFee = gasUsed.mul(gasPricePaid);
```

##### [`provider.getGasPrice`](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-monorepo/blob/ecd7b5d62dd874559bc059ec2da6a343a72bb634/packages/client/lib/rpc/modules/eth.ts#L1033)

— returns suggested gas price for current/next transactions. You call this **before** sending the transaction, to estimate the gas price.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense now. Can you elaborate briefly what is the difference? effectiveGasPrice is the price paid after the contract is deployed and getGasPrice is just the price that is predicted before deployment .

Answer (score 1):

I always use Remix. Connect to local host -> select your smart contract -> compile -> choose from Metamask the chain -> inject Metamask in Remix -> deploy -> Metamask will pop up with the necessary gas and cost to deploy ->then cancel. This will also give info about the price of gas at that moment.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there’s no way (wei) in hell you’ll pay such a little amount of wei to deploy any contract ever. That figure is in ETH.

The reason for the discrepancy took me a while to read into

The thing to consider is that, as seen in [this](https://twitter.com/timbeiko/status/1413535112071761924?s=46&t=AeOhO10df0bf4c2d4rCYKw) thread, `effectiveGasPrice` is actually the result of `base fee + priority fee`.

Indeed now `effectiveGasPrice` In the tx receipt